# Is it possible to install windows 10 on VHD/VHDX and boot from it on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, linux-mint

Is it possible to boot Windows from a VHD file that is stored on a Linux partition?

I don't want to run Windows under VirtualBox. Linux is the only OS on the hard drive, and Windows should only exist on the VHD.

He asked the same question and if anybody can help that would be great.

[Is it possible to boot a Windows VHD using GRUB on a physical machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/638438/is-it-possible-to-boot-a-windows-vhd-using-grub-on-a-physical-machine)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to boot a Windows VHD using GRUB on a physical machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/638438/is-it-possible-to-boot-a-windows-vhd-using-grub-on-a-physical-machine)

Comment: The other question has valid answers. The summary: Windows must handle the filesystem the VHD(X) resides on. If you think your question is not a duplicate, please elaborate.